Unable to Limit d -> infinity whilst calculating length of curve between 2 points.
$$f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$$ (Function doesn't matter its for more easily telling when its correct)
$$ \int_{\left(-1\right)d}^{\left(1\right)d}\sqrt{\left(\left|f\left(x\frac{a}{d}+\frac{a}{d}\right)-f\left(x\frac{a}{d}\right)\right|\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{a}{d}\right)^{2}}dx $$
or
$$d\int_{\left(-1\right)}^{\left(1\right)}\sqrt{\left(\left|f\left(x+\frac{a}{d}\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{a}{d}\right)^{2}}dx$$
or
$$\sum_{n=-d}^{d}\ \sqrt{\left(f\left(n\frac{a}{d}+\frac{a}{d}\right)-f\left(n\frac{a}{d}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{a}{d}\right)^{2}}$$
I am new to asking on the math stack exchange so I may make mistakes, sorry in advance.
I was messing around and attempting to calculate the length of a curve between 2 points and ended up with this equation where as d grows larger the answer gets more accurate. but when I attempted taking the limit of d -> infinity I was unable to solve it. When i asked my math teacher he was also unable to solve.
Either equation would work for a solution.
For some context this doesn't currently work because a/d is finite.
The equation is based off of Pythagorean theorem between two very close points.
It currently works for linear equations and the function attached is for simplicity as the answer should be pi.
Visualization of what's happening:


Welcome to math.SE. It's generally asked that you put all the relevant information in your question without linking to images. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Could you also lay out a bit more of the context that led to these expressions - i.e. what actual length you're trying to calculate, and how these integrals are meant to approximate it.

@ConMan I have added more is this enough info to properly show what's happening?

So it looks like what you're doing is trying to calculate the arc length of a curve, but your notation is a little wonky - for one thing, when you take the limit to go from a sum to an integral the $\frac{a}{d}$ terms should also be disappearing since they're affected by the limit too.
If we look at the curve from $x = a$ to $x = b$ and break it into pieces at the points $x_0 = a, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n = b$ and define $\Delta x_j = x_j - x_{j-1}$ and $\Delta y_j = f(x_j) = f(x_{j-1})$, then as you've noticed the length of the segment between $x_{j-1}$ and $x_j$ is equal to
$$L_j = \sqrt{\Delta x_j^2 + \Delta y_j^2}$$
so the total length of our approximation is the sum of all of those values. We can also rearrange it a little bit to get
$$L \approx \sum_{j = 1}^n L_j = \sum_{j = 1}^n \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\Delta y_j}{\Delta x_j} \right)^2} \Delta x_j$$
Now I'm going to be very loose with this, but you can prove this more properly, but when you take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, you can take the sum as a Riemann sum and turn it into an integral, but also $\frac{\Delta y_j}{\Delta x_j}$ approaches $\frac{dy}{dx}$, meaning that
$$L = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx$$
If you try your example function $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$, I recommend looking at using a trigonometric substitution and you'll find it simplifies exactly as you want it to.
